# Total Variation Distance between 2 distributions

Tags: probability, solution-verification, markov-chains

Consider **n** cards. Let $\mu$ be a  uniform distribution of all permutations of $n$ cards.
However, let $\nu$ be a uniform distribution on all such permutations where the first card is dealt. Calculate $d_{TV}(\mu,\nu)$.

Note: Given formula for Total variation Distance :

$d_{TV}(\mu,\nu) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{e\in E} |\mu(e)-\nu(e)|$

Do you think my solution is on the right lines ?

My attempt :

I have been thinking on the solution, and here is what I think.

**μ** : Uniform distribution of n cards : n!

1st card can be dealt with in : n ways uniformly

2nd card can be dealt with in : (n-1) ways uniformly

3rd card : (n-2) ways ...
...
..
..

**μ**<sup>n</sup><sub>1</sub>= $\frac{1}{n}$,**μ**<sup>n</sup><sub>2</sub>= $\frac{1}{n-1}$ and so on..

For the distribution **ν**, it is said that, first card is already dealt with :

**My interpretation** : 1st card can be dealt with in **n** ways uniformly.

And the same distribution for the rest of the cards.

So, as per my understanding d<sub>TV</sub>(**μ**,**ν**)  = **0**

But, not sure on my answer..
Please add your comments or another approach to look at the problem and solve it.

Comment: I doubt that interpretation is what was intended.  Perhaps you should consider the cases where the first card dealt is known (so treat it as fixed, not uniformly distributed)

Comment: ok. So.. if we consider 1st card as known and already dealt with.. like fixed.